# make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 2 - error when using 'make -j'

Tags: makefile

I have a custom Makefile system (massive and modular) and I am attempting a make -j. It takes almost 10 minutes to get there and successfully processes 3740 compilation steps in parallel. At this point there are 6 that are mid-process and I get this opaque error:
make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 2

There is no practical difference between these 3740 and the subsequent thousands more compilations that remain. Each step is compiling a block with inter-dependencies and the like. I have tried debug switches, but they very quickly (within minutes) generate 10's of GBs of data and it will overtake my disk space. Also, none of the switches seem like they'll be that helpful - suggestions appreciated.

If I continue the process with the same 'make -j' command, it completes fine.

The whole thing builds perfect with just 'make'. It's 'make -j' that has this 1 failure in the middle.

There could be something special about the inter-dependencies of these 6 that keep failing, but I can't fathom what - they are just 6 more of a huge number of Makefiles and steps.

Update: I found a missing dependency (updated my automatic dependency build flow), but I don't think that was causing the failure, just the new dependencies are changing the compile. But for now the issue is gone.

Comment: Can you narrow it down at all? How about `make -j 5'? How about `make -j` on one of those six targets? How about `make` on one of the six, followed by a general `make -j`?

Comment: I'll try to narrow it down using make -j x (and starting with x == 5 sounds smart given it's 6 outstanding. Thanks! I'll also see if different make versions matter.

I can't specify these 6 targets without all the rest being built first, but perhaps that could give some insight.

Comment: make -j 5 passes this point without failure.

Comment: The message suggests that a command at line 3 in Makefile exits with return code 2. Is there an error message from the failing command? If not, why? It may help debugging syncronizing parallel output with "make -O".

Comment: Thanks Andreas! I didn't even realize there was a -O switch. Will use that and hope it sheds some light on what is going on.

Comment: When using `make`'s `-j` option breaks a build that works without `-j`, it is ordinarily because the makefile(s) do not capture all the relevant dependency information.  Serial builds may nevertheless work reliably because of `make` implementation details, such as updating each target's prerequisites in the order they are listed in the build rule chosen for that target, that do not apply to parallel builds.